# How to code my app to receive content from other apps

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I following [this tutorial](http://home.cofares.net/androidDocs/training/sharing/receive.html) from **Android Developers** to code my app to receive text sent from other apps (specifically to deal with text sent from Share from Browser).

I want the shared text to appear in the EditText box of my app (as it appears automatically in the body of New Message when Messaging is called to share).

Here is what I have done:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } 
    } 
    else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
```

---

```
void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        this.edWord.setText(sharedText);

    }
}
```

And I have declared `private EditText edWord = null;`and updated Manifest as required.
However, Eclipse always throws the following errors:

```
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{doyle.myapp/doyle.myapp.Myapp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at doyle.myapp.Myapp.handleSendText(Myapp.java:573)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at doyle.myapp.Myapp.onCreate(Myapp.java:437)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-17 16:32:08.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     ... 11 more
```

**I wonder what is wrong with my code. What should I do to solve the problem? Can you please help?**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Which line is Myapp.java:573 ?

Comment: Your problem is not with android. It's with java and debugging. I'd recommend studying some java before proceeding

Comment: if edWord is declared as NULL, how it is able to do setText() ? Follow Thepoosh

Answer (score 2):

have you tried debugging and looking at the value of `sharedText`?

***UPDATE***

just noticed that you said

> And I have declared private EditText edWord = null;and updated Manifest as required.

if you don't create a new View or inflate an xml layout view, the EditText will not be connected to anything. try doing something like this:

```
edWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edText);
```

or creating a new edittext in your context.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I have `public void menuMain()
    {
  //Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "Start menuMain");
        
     edWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
     lstWord = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstWord);`

Comment: in this case, may I refer you to the beginning of my answer, try debugging and going step-by-step and checking the value of all the needed objects

Comment: Let me clarify it: my app works just fine, nothing wrong with it. Now I just want it to accept text sent to it from other apps.

Comment: in what line exactly does it crash? does it pass the `if (sharedText != null)`?

Comment: Thanks, Thepoosh. I'm debugging it now. Could you help me more?

Comment: let me know exactly where the crash happens

Comment: The debugger gets stuck at "Attempting to connect debugger to 'doyle.myapp' on port 8631"

Comment: try closing all the android tools (DDMS and others) re-launching eclipse and try again

Comment: OK, do it now. Anyway, do you think it's better if you can see my code? You can see my desktop here https://join.me/772-210-588

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11371/discussion-between-niamh-doyle-and-thepoosh)

Answer (score 1):

are you initializing the edWord by findViewById or not Please check is it null?